# ClassNotFoundException inside AST transformation

Tags: gradle, groovy

In my class I have such code

```
import com.lapots.game.journey.core.platform.ManagedPlatform

class ApplicationMain {

    def lifeFramework = ManagedPlatform["lifeFramework"]

}
```

I decided to implement `AST` that would work similar to bean injection

```
@Managed("lifeFramework")
def lifeFramework
```

It supposed to set initial value expression for the fields that have such annotation. Basically replace with

```
def lifeFramework = com.lapots.game.journey.core.platform.ManagedPlatform.getAt("lifeFramework")
```

It is not as similar as I have in the original but unfortunately I do not know how to implicitely add `import` and `[]` expressions (it is replaced with `getAt` anyway).

Here is my annotation declaration

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target([ElementType.FIELD])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(["com.lapots.game.journey.ast.managed.ManagedASTTransformation"])
public @interface Managed {
    String value()
}
```

And here is the implementation

```
import static org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GeneralUtils.callX
import static org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GeneralUtils.args

@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase=CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
class ManagedASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {

    private static final String DEFAULT_MEMBER = "value"
    private static final String MANAGED_STORAGE = "com.lapots.game.journey.core.platform.ManagedPlatform"

    @Override
    void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source) {
        AnnotatedNode parent = (AnnotatedNode) nodes[1]
        AnnotationNode node = (AnnotationNode) nodes[0]

        if (parent in FieldNode) {
            def beanName = node.getMember(DEFAULT_MEMBER).text
            final FieldNode fieldNode = (FieldNode) parent
            fieldNode.setInitialValueExpression(createInvocationExpression(beanName))
        }
    }

    private StaticMethodCallExpression createInvocationExpression(String bean) {
        def classNode = new ClassNode(Class.forName(MANAGED_STORAGE))
        return callX(classNode, "getAt", args(bean))
    }
}
```

My `AST` transformation is located inside subproject `ast`.

```
ast\
   src\main\groovy\...\Managed
```

My `ApplicationMain` class and overall `ManagedPlatform` is located inside subproject `core`

```
core\
   src\main\groovy\...\ApplicationMain
                      \ManagedPlatform
```

and that subproject has `ast` subproject as `compile` depedency

```
dependencies {
   compile project(":ast")
}
```

When I try to run my application I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lapots.game.journey.core.platform.ManagedPlatform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.lapots.game.journey.ast.managed.ManagedASTTransformation.createInvocationExpression(ManagedASTTransformation.groovy:49)
    at com.lapots.game.journey.ast.managed.ManagedASTTransformation.visit(ManagedASTTransformation.groovy:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.visitClass(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$2.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:178)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1053)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:525)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonServer.execute(CompilerDaemonServer.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems it is unabled to find `ManagedPlatform` class (might because it located in another subproject)

How to make `AST` see my class from another `subproject`? Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: And`:core` is a dependency of your main code you're trying to run?

Comment: @tim_yates yes it is